# Clarity Forms - Place multiple input elements on same row

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I am trying to use [Clarity Forms](https://v2.clarity.design/forms) to create something like below:

[image: Design: Multi fields on same row]

However, it looks like all the Clarity input elements when used within form gets wrapped into `<clr-xxx-container>` which has class `clr-row` applied to it.  Thus, it seems impossible to place two input elements next to each other and take benefit of Clarity Form Elements.

Is my understanding correct or I am missing something?

My code looks like below:

```
   <form clrForm clrLayout="horizontal">
        <clr-input-container>
            <label>Disk Capacity</label>
            <input clrInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="model" name="example" required />

            <clr-control-helper>Disk capacity to add to VM</clr-control-helper>
            <clr-control-error>Error message that appears after focus is lost and control is invalid</clr-control-error>
        </clr-input-container>
        <select clrSelect name="options" [(ngModel)]="options">
            <option value="GB">GB</option>
            <option value="TB">TB</option>
            <option value="PB">PB</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-v2-forms-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clarity has the basic design, but not built-in Angular support for this yet. You will have to use the HTML/CSS version of the forms for this, because we haven't yet defined how to do built-in validation with multiple controls in the same line.

See the demo source here: https://github.com/vmware/clarity/tree/master/src/dev/src/app/forms/input-group

Long term, this is a feature request here: https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/3778